# Does Azuredevops support running automated tests from test plans on Linux/Ubuntu agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As far as I know we can Run automated tests from test plans on Windows agent by using "vstest". Do we have any support/ way to run automated tests from test plans on Linux boxes?

As per azure doc: To run automated tests from test plans, we would need "vstest" to be installed on agent box. However, since we are using Linux box - do we have any alternative?

[image: error message screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment?view=azure-devops#demands-and-prerequisites):

[image]

The reason for why you are facing the error after run the **Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment** task, is the OS of the agent you are using does not meet its requirement.

Until now, we only support the **Windows-based machines** for this [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment?view=azure-devops#supported-scenarios):

[image]

Also, we have hardcode this requirement into our [task definition](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTestPlatformToolInstallerV1/vstestplatformtoolinstaller.ts#L22). This means there's no any work around can for you use if the agent you want to use is Ubuntu. Because we has script to firstly check the environment, to see whether it meets the requirements of the task.

You can raise a suggestion request on our [official forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to expand this feature into Azure Devops. Our PM would review it and kindly to consider to take it into our develop roadmap.

Comment: @VaradarajKamath , I'd suggest you to use Windows Hosted/Private agent to run the VStest now. It is a huge work to configure and check the visual studio component in Linux OS. If anyone has the same demand with you, they will vote and comment there to advance the priority of it, to make it could be develop and expanded into Azure Devops as soon as possible. Also, if my answer could help you solve your puzzle, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thus others who has the puzzle with you can refer to this answer:-)

Comment: @VaradarajKamath , If still has other puzzle about it, feel free to leave comment here.